# proguard does not create output jar

Tags: java, proguard

I'm running `proguard` on a single class file but the `output.jar` file is **not created**.

```
$ javap -c java-8-classes/BinaryNode.class | sed -n "139,150p;151q"
  public int hashCode();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #2                  // Field _data:[B
       4: ifnonnull     11
       7: iconst_m1
       8: goto          16
      11: aload_0
      12: getfield      #2                  // Field _data:[B
      15: arraylength
      16: ireturn
```

So unless I'm mistaken(?) it seems that `BinaryNode::hashCode` only needs `_data` field.

```
$ javap -c java-8-classes/BinaryNode.class | sed -n "5,6p;7q"
  protected final byte[] _data;
```

So I edited my `config.pro` accordingly:

```
$ cat config.pro
-injars java-8-classes/BinaryNode.class
-outjars output.jar
-verbose
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.BinaryNode
{
    protected final byte[] _data;
    public int hashCode();
}
-allowaccessmodification
```

When I run proguard, output jar does **not** get created:

```
$ java -jar ../proguard/lib/proguard.jar -dontwarn @config.pro
ProGuard, version 7.1.0-beta2
Reading input...
Reading program directory [/home/oren/Documents/java-8-classes/BinaryNode.class] (filtered) # <---- OK??
Initializing...
<...>
Preparing output jar [/home/oren/Documents/output.jar] (filtered) # <---- WHY ???
```

Comment: can you try with non-beta version of proguard. by look of it everythings looks good. try 6.0.1 and process the output again.

Comment: The option name `-injars` suggests that it expects jar files, not a class file.

Comment: Answered here: https://community.guardsquare.com/t/proguard-fails-to-create-output-jar/644 - the entire jar was needed ...